# Why does the DSolve solution to the Cauchy-Euler differential equation not match the analytical solution?

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic

SOLVED: Issue was an embarrassing typo... (missed the ^ symbol in my hand solution)

I'm trying to solve the [Cauchy-Euler differential equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerDifferentialEquation.html) and so I decided to try two approaches: 1) use `DSolve` to solve the equation in Mathematica and 2) to use the analytical solution and then use Mathematica to just solve the algebra for the boundary conditions. However, I'm running into solutions from the two routes that I *think* should be equal but Mathematica says are not the same.

The homogeneous differential equation is
$$r^2\frac{\text{d}^2v}{\text{d}r^2} + \alpha r \frac{\text{d}v}{\text{d}r} + \beta v(r) = 0$$
and when $(\alpha -1)^2 > 4\beta$, the solution I believe should be of the form*
$$v(r) = C_1 r^{a+b} + C_2 r^{a-b}$$
where
$$a = \frac{1-\alpha}{2},$$
$$b = \frac{\sqrt{-4\beta + (\alpha -1)^2}}{2},$$
and $C_1$ and $C_2$ are constants of integration.
This solution comes from guessing a solution of the form $r^m$, plugging in, and solving the [characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation) for the roots $a+b$ and $a-b$.

However, when I plug in $\alpha = 2$ and $\beta = -4$ and ask Mathematica to compare my analytical solution to the `DSolve` solution through the `==` operator, it says they differ. This is the mathematica notebook I'm using:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
lineareqn = r^2*v''[r] + \[Alpha]*r*v'[r] + \[Beta]*v[r] == 0
matsoln = DSolve[lineareqn, v[r], r]
compsoln = matsoln[[1]][[1]][[2]] /. {C[1] -> A, C[2] -> B}
a = 1/2*(1 - \[Alpha])
b = 1/2*Sqrt[-4*\[Beta]  + (\[Alpha] - 1)^2]
handsoln = A*r^(a + b) + B*r (a - b)
Simplify[compsoln == handsoln /. {\[Alpha] -> 2, \[Beta] -> -4}, r > 0]
```

I think it should just return `True`, it instead returns
$$2 A \left(r^{\sqrt{17}}-1\right)=B r^{\frac{\sqrt{17}}{2}} \left(\left(\sqrt{17}+1\right) r^{3/2}+2 r^{\frac{\sqrt{17}}{2}}\right)$$

What's going on here?

*Actually, I believe this form should be valid for real or complex roots but is more convenient for real roots.

Comment: Could it be that in the `B` term of your `handsol` you don't have the power (`^`) ?

Comment: That's embarrassing! Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Interestingly, I also noticed that when using $\beta$ as a constant, Mathematica says the answers agree. However, in the actual equation I'm solving, $\beta = -1/\sin^{2}\theta$ and for this, the computed and hand solutions are different. Plugging numbers into them though, the solutions are the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually  you're mostly fine. You just have two typos:

1) As b.gatessucks commented, you forgot to type a power (`^`) in the `r^(a-b)` part of `handsoln`

i.e. you want: `handsoln = A*r^(a + b) + B*r^(a - b)`

2) Given the above convention for your handsoln, you swapped which of $\{A,B\}$ was C[1], and which was C[2], so in your `compsoln`
you want: `compsoln= matsoln[[1]][[1]][[2]] /. {C[1] -> B, C[2] -> A}`

Then you don't even need to plug in numbers (though I completely respect the impulse!)

`compsoln - handsoln // ExpandAll` $\mapsto$ `0`

Comment: Thanks you for finding the second issue as well! Originally I thought my roots were complex so I was afraid that Mathematica wouldn't properly see the solutions as equal. Good to know that it should work regardless!

Comment: Interestingly when I use $\beta = -1/\sin^{2}\theta$, Mathematica says the solutions are now different somehow.

Comment: You're still fine :-).  If you plug in: `\[Beta] -> -Csc[\[Theta]]^2` before  you use `DSolve`, then it just scales the constants of integration: `{C[1] -> B, C[2] -> A*Sqrt[1 - 2*\[Alpha] + \[Alpha]^2 + 4*Csc[\[Theta]]^2]}` .

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

You hand solution seems to be wrong somewhere. I have not checked why it does not match Mathematica's but here is my hand solution and it agrees with Mathematica's. May be you made a typo somewhere.

Solve

$$
r^{2}v^{\prime\prime}+\alpha rv^{\prime}+\beta v=0
$$

Let $v=r^{m}$ then $v^{\prime}=mr^{m-1},v^{\prime\prime}=m\left(  m-1\right)
r^{m-2}$ and the above becomes

\begin{align*}
r^{2}m\left(  m-1\right)  r^{m-2}+\alpha rmr^{m-1}+\beta r^{m}  & =0\\
m\left(  m-1\right)  +\alpha m+\beta & =0\\
m^{2}-m+\alpha m+\beta & =0\\
m^{2}+m\left(  \alpha-1\right)  +\beta & =0
\end{align*}

Roots are
\begin{align*}
m_{1}  & =\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\alpha^{2}-2\alpha-4\beta+1}-\frac{1}{2}%
\alpha+\frac{1}{2}\\
m_{2}  & =\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\alpha^{2}-2\alpha-4\beta
+1}- \frac{1}{2}\alpha
\end{align*}

Hence the solution is

\begin{align*}
v\left(  r\right)    & =C_{1}r^{m_{1}}+C_{2}r^{m_{2}}\\
& =C_{1}r^{\left(  \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\alpha^{2}-2\alpha-4\beta+1}-\frac{1}
{2}\alpha+\frac{1}{2}\right)  }+C_{2}r^{\left(  \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}
\sqrt{\alpha^{2}-2\alpha-4\beta+1}-\frac{1}{2}\alpha\right)  }
\end{align*}

At $\alpha=2,\beta=-4$ the above is

\begin{align*}
v\left(  r\right)    & =C_{1}r^{\left(  \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2^{2}-2\left(
2\right)  -4\left(  -4\right)  +1}-\frac{1}{2}\left(  2\right)  +\frac{1}
{2}\right)  }+C_{2}r^{\left(  \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2^{2}-2\left(
2\right)  -4\left(  -4\right)  +1}- \frac{1}{2}\left(  2\right)
\right)  }\\
& =C_{1}r^{\left(  \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{17}-\frac{1}{2}\right)  }+C_{2}r^{\left(
-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{17}-\frac{1}{2}\right)  }
\end{align*}

Mathematica gives

```
ClearAll[alpha, beta, v, r]
lineareqn=r^2*v''[r]+alpha*r*v'[r]+beta*v[r]==0
matsoln=DSolve[lineareqn,v[r],r]
matsoln/.{alpha->2,beta->-4}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or to see it more clearly

```
specific=v[r]/.First[matsoln/.{alpha->2,beta->-4}];
specific/.r^(any_):>  r^(Expand[any])
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which is the same.  QED.

Comment: Brought down by a typo! Thanks for checking the math!